# RegExp для поиска совпадения по шаблону

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Написал регулярку для проверки строки такого вида:

```
100_Some_string_there_v12
```

Сама регулярка `/(\d+_)|(_v\d+)/` находит как и нужно `100_` и `_v12` (я их в дальнейшем откидываю и использую оставшуюся строку `Some_string_there`).

Но как быть если в строке, которую мне нужно получить будет число?

Например входная строка будет `100_7_Some_string_11_there_2001_v12`, из которой мне надо получить центральную часть (`7_Some_string_11_there_2001`).

Подскажите как написать регулярку для такой проверки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
^\d+_|_v\d+$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ZKNfzb/1)

Здесь `^` обозначает начало строки, а `$` — её конец.

[Пример кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/0Usit):

```
preg_replace('~^\d+_|_v\d+$~', '', '100_7_Some_string_11_there_2001_v12')
```

Comment: Благодарю. То что нужно!

Comment: А если строка будет такого вида? domain@100_7_Some_string_11_there_2001_v12.sub.exp

Comment: @makbeth `'~^[^_]+_|_[^_]+$~'`, `[^_]` — исключающий символьный класс, который находит любой символ, кроме `_`

Comment: Круто! Работает замечательно!